# AWS Load Balancer giving 302 on include

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-elb

I am trying to configure 2 EC2 instances on the top of a load balancer. Our Application is running on Apache and uses Coldfusion 9 as application server. Since we have placed a load balancer it has started giving 302 . But if we try to use the same form on stand alone instance, then it works fine.

The line ate which it has started giving error is this -

```
<cfsavecontent variable="sResponse">
    <cfinclude template="views/region/#this.getRegion()#/#sResponse.data[2]['view']#" />
</cfsavecontent>
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Is there any apache configuration that needs to go here?

Comment: Hmmm... a little confused. How are you getting a line number? a 302 is a redirect or "resource moved" and includes an alternate path yes? Your description makes it sound like a ColdFusion error. My first guess would be that the load balancer is incorrectly directing traffic.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am getting 302 Moved temporarily. It is not a CF error because it is working fine on each instance individually. It only stops working when I use LB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It was my mistake in the configuration of LB. I was not using sticky sessions and hence the LB was directing request to other instance on each request.